# Prove that the group is of measure zero.

Tags: measure-theory

I have the question:

Let $A\subset  \mathbb{R}^n$ and $D \subset  \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $ D=\{a_1x_1+...a_nx_n=d\}$.

Prove that f $A\subset D$ then $A$ has measure zero and if $A$ is closed and bounded then it has volume zero.

I am not sure how to start to prove that it is of measure zero. In addition, I noticed that is $A$ is bounded then we can cover it with one cuboid then it is of volume zero but why do we need it to be closed ?

I would be happy to get a direction.
Thank you!

Comment: You need to be a little more precise, if $d=a_k = 0$ then $D$ is the entire space.

Comment: Without loss of generality you can suppose $D=\{x_1=0\}$. This is an hyperplane. Does that help you?

Comment: Obviously it's both necessary and sufficient to prove that $D$ has measure zero in $\Bbb R^n$.  What do you know about outer measures in $\Bbb R^n$?

Comment: For compact sets, the Riemann volume and Lebesgue measure coincide since any countable cover by intervals reduces to a finite one.